# Regular Expression accepting only 9 digits, no special characters , not all zero's and should not start with zero

Tags: regex

Hi i need a Regular Expression which is accepting only Numbers from 0-9 ,but  should not contain all Zeros ,should not contain special characters , should not start with zero and with a length of exact 9 digits.

I tried this one but it is accepting special characters at last.
^[1-9][0-9]{8}

Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a ending character at the end `$`

```
 ^[1-9][0-9]{8}$
```

Comment: i have one more requirement can you please provide a solution for my requirement,
My requirement is 
A regular expression that may accept leading zero's only up to 2
Regular expression  should accept
012312312
001231231
123123123
these 3 patterns. Please help me out..

Comment: `^(?!000)[0-9]{9}$` That should probably do it. It uses a look-around at the first position to make sure there is no "000" there. More on [negative matching is in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5334825/5520354)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
^[1-9]\d{8}$
```

Not sure why you are seeing special characters at the end unless it's after the 9 digits. the `$` will solve that problem.

Additionally I prefer the use of character classes when applicable (`\d` for any digit). I think it makes, sometimes very complicated, Regex easier to read than groups.

Answer (score 0):

Try this change

^[1-9]\d{8}

I hope it works